# Python Add element with key equal to 8

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I have this code to run in Python:

```
squares = {1:1,2:3,3:"error",4:16,}
squares[3]=9
squares[8] =64
print(squares)
```

The result I got is:

```
{8: 64, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 9, 4: 16}
```

When I tried to replace the `8` by, for example, `5` as the code below shows:

```
squares = {1:1,2:3,3:"error",4:16,}
squares[3]=9
squares[5] =64
print(squares)
```

I got the following result:

```
{1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 64}
```

Can someone explain why in the first piece of code the element was added in the beginning while in the last one it was added at the end of the dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary are not ordered!

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is not ordered. The sequence of elements doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) first:

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an **unordered** set of *key: value* pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

So it is meaningless to distinguish between *beginning* and *end*.

Answer (score 1):

As previous answers have pointed out, the items of a dictionary are unordered. If you want to print the content of your 'square' dictionary with the key ordered, you could do:

```
print(sorted(squares))
```

This will print the content of the dictionary as (key, value) pairs, ordered by key:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16), (5, 25), (8, 64)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements of a dictionary are displayed in a deterministic order. However, in contrast to what one might expect, they are not arranged in lexicographical order.

You can use the method `dict.items()` and the built-in funtion `sorted()` to display the content of a dictionary with either the keys or the values ordered lexicographically:

```
>>> somedict = {7:'a', 6:'c', 8:'b'}
>>> print(somedict)
{8: 'b', 6: 'c', 7: 'a'}
>>> print(sorted(somedict.items()))
[(6, 'a'), (7, 'c'), (8, 'b')]
>>> print(sorted(somedict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
[(7, 'a'), (8, 'b'), (6, 'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This used to trip me up too as a beginner. Unlike lists, dictionaries are not ordered. In other words, you can't depend on the order the key/value pairs will appear when you print the contents of a dictionary. If you really need them to be ordered, you can use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).